# Oracle SQL: Limiting multiple where clauses

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologies if this seems like a duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981913/sql-oracle-rownum-on-multiple-where-clauses) but I believe my use case is slightly different.

I have two tables.

```
Table1

ID                  INTCODE
-----------------------------
000019827364        1
000019829201        2
890418392101        3
890418390395        4
890418398677        5
505586578932        6
505586578914        7
505586578933        8
505586578012        9
490201827383        10
490201827466        11
001952046578        12


Table2

INTCODE     Category
-------------------------
1           Display
2           Display
3           Display
4           Display
5           Display
6           Audio
7           Audio
8           Audio
9           Audio
10          Audio
11          Audio
12          Audio
```

My expected query results are all possible 5 digit prefixes of each category and in each of these prefixes - I want to extract at least 2 full IDs. Below is an example if I had a where clause for category as 'Display'.

```
ID PREFIX       Category    ID  
----------------------------------------------- 
00001           Display     000019827364
00001           Display     000019829201
89041           Display     890418392101
89041           Display     890418390395
```

The query I currently have is

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(t1.ID, 1, 5)
FROM
    table1 t1
    ,table2 t2
WHERE
    AND UPPER(t2.category) = 'DISPLAY'
    AND t2.REGION_ID = 1
    AND t2.ZONE_ID = 2
    AND t1.REGION_ID = 1
    AND t1.ZONE_ID = 2
    AND t1.INTCODE = t2.INTCODE
GROUP BY
    SUBSTR(t1.ID, 1, 5)
```

I am now kind of lost. Should I be running another query where I say

```
t1.ID LIKE '00001%'
OR LIKE '89041%'
```

This list will go on to be huge cause some of the categories have 400-500 prefixes. Is there a better way to go about this? Possibly in a single query?

I'm using Oracle SQL.

Many thanks!

Comment: So you need another table with the prefixed in it?

Comment: Use an union with a max, and min for the second select.

Comment: My query results should have the prefixes with the category and also 2 full IDs. I have an example of how my results should look like

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: I'm fairly new to SQL, Just started about a month ago. Can you please help me with an example? Thank you!

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya Just wrote you a sample snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` for this:

```
select Category, ID, IDPrefix
from (select Category, ID, SUBSTR(ID, 1, 5) as IDPREFIX,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTR(ID, 1, 5) ORDER BY ID) as seqnum
      FROM table1 JOIN
           table2 t2
           ON t1.INTCODE = t2.INTCODE ANd
              t1.Region_id = t2.Region_id and
              t1.zone_id = t2.zone_id
      WHERE UPPER(t2.category) = 'DISPLAY'
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff! I am now reading up about how rownum and partition work :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can to display two rows with different Id, without any more constraint, you could simply use an `union` where the first query would select the max id, and the second query the min id.

So your query would look something like this

```
select id_prefix, category, max(id)
from yourTable
union
select id_prefix, category, min(id)
from yourTable
```

Now simply add to this algorithm your where conditions.